# avoiding duplicate instances of an object with random variables

Tags: python, class, random

I've been struggling to find a simple enough solution to the following problem:

Let's say I have a class with two variables defined, like below (points on a x-y grid):

```py
class Target:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.x = random.randint(1, 9)  
        self.y = random.randint(1, 9)
```

I need to generate a given amount of those, let's say 10:

```py
for i in range(10):  
    t = Target()
```

Of course, sometimes the coordinates overlap.

What would be the simplest way to assure none of the objects have the same x and y variables? I've been trying some solutions, but they feel overwrought and I feel there must be a relatively simple one.

Comment: please use back ticks for insertig code in code formatting

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to avoid creating duplicated instances (what would you do after creating 81 instances?) or you want 10 different instances (which would better be in a container, maybe a set).

Comment: Take a look at this: [Prevent duplicate objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414409)

Comment: By "overlap" you mean `a.x == b.x and a.y == b.y`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

First, adjust your class to take the `x` and `y` coordinates as initialization parameters.

```
class Target:
    def __init__(self, x, y):  
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Then you could generate a list of all valid coordinate pairs.

```
xy = [(x, y) for x in range(1, 10) for y in range(1, 10)]
```

Then take a random sample of size 10 without replacement.

```
xy_sample = random.sample(xy, 10)
```

Then initialize 10 instances of your class.

```
targets = [Target(x, y) for x, y in xy_sample]
```

Caveat: if the xy-space is huge then just keeping track of the generated `x`, `y` pairs in a set and rerolling the randomly generated numbers in the unlikely case that you hit a duplicate may be more feasible.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I realize I misunderstood the question !

Comment: `xy` can be created with `list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 2))` too

Comment: Thanks to all, this is nice and simple - however, the range should be (1, 10) - the right boundary is excluded in a generator, unlike in ```random.randint```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your class constructor's interface is set and you can't change it (or don't want to), so the randomization part needs to be inside `__init__`. And also assuming that just "assuring" there are no dupes in a list of `Target`s is primarily what you want, without any further assumptions made on what you're exactly trying to achieve.

Then, as a first step, you would require for the `Target`s to be comparable to each other, based on their `x` and `y` values.This can be implemented in the `__eq__` method:

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
     return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

Alongside, you need to create `__hash__`, which is required to be equal for objects that are equal based on `__eq__`, and also because reimplementing `__eq__` resets the default `__hash__` so `Target` wouldn't be hashable without:

```py
def __hash__(self):
     return hash((self.x, self.y))  # just use the tuple's hash
```

Now you can compare `Target`s with one another based on their `(x,y)` data:

```py
Target() == Target()
```

This worked before, too, but would return if the two targets are the same object, which may be `False` even with the same x and y.

With this as the basis, you can now assert there are no dupes in your list of targets

```py
targets = [Target() for in range(10)]
```

by turning it into a `set`, which removes dupes based on equality based on `__eq__`, and then comparing the length of the result:

```py
assert len(targets) == len(set(targets))
```

This is may not be what makes the most sense to do, but a direct answer to your question nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a generator that remebers the old choices.
Carefull: The function can turn into an infinity loop if you create more classes of Target than there are available combinations...

```
import numpy as np

class CustomGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int):
        self.old_values = []
        self.lower_bound = lower_bound
        self.upper_bound = upper_bound

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        while True:
            new_vals = tuple(np.random.randint(self.lower_bound, self.upper_bound, 2))
            if new_vals not in self.old_values:
                break
        return new_vals

gen = CustomGenerator(0, 100)

class Target:
    def __init__(self, gen):  
        self.x, self.y = next(gen)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.x}, {self.y}"

t = Target(gen)
print(t)
```